# Programmatically edit a large word document using C#

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

I am trying to copy paste certain fields from one large word doc file into another programmatically.
The file to copy from was converted to word from a pdf image file. It has the following format:

[Construction Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS1db.jpg)

The word template to copy to has this format:

[Supervision Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5HIi.jpg)

My code can copy paste the data correctly for the first page of the construction log into the supervision log but not the second and third so on...

Here is my code:

```
       using System;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

        namespace LogConverter
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var fileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\Construction Logs.docx";

                        var wordApp = new Word.Application();
                        wordApp.Visible = true;
                        var document = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName);

                        string filePath = Application.StartupPath + @"\Supervision Logs.dotx";
                        Word.Application LogApp = new Word.Application();
                        Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(filePath);
                        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                        wordApp.Visible = true;
                        Word.Selection selection = wordApp.Selection;

                        Word.Range rangeDoc = wordDoc.Range();

                        int PageCnt = 1;
                        SearchPerPage(wordDoc, oMissing, selection, rangeDoc, document, PageCnt);
                        PageCnt++;

                        wordApp.Documents.Close();
                        LogApp.Documents.Close();
                        wordApp.Quit();
                        LogApp.Quit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }            
                }

                static void SearchPerPage(Word.Document wordDoc, object oMissing, Word.Selection selection, Word.Range rangeDoc, Word.Document document, int pageCnt)
                {
                    foreach (Word.Range storyRange in document.StoryRanges)
                    {
                        var range = storyRange;
// I have changed the while loop to loop till end of the document i.e last paragraph
                           while (range != null && 
 range!=document.Paragraphs.Last)
                        {
                            //Get string between two strings in a string
                            String St = storyRange.Text;

                            if (!St.Contains("Date")) continue;

                            //Get Date portion of record
                            int DateFrom = St.IndexOf("Date:") + "Date:".Length;
                            int DateTo = St.IndexOf("Weather:");
                            string Date = St.Substring(DateFrom, DateTo - DateFrom);

                            //Get Temperature portion of record
                            int TempFrom = St.IndexOf("Temperature:") + "Temperature:".Length;
                            int TempTo = St.IndexOf("I .Construction");
                            string Temperature = St.Substring(TempFrom, TempTo - TempFrom);

                            //Get Construction work portion of record
                            int ConsFrom = St.IndexOf("Construction Work") + "Construction Work".Length;
                            int ConsTo = St.IndexOf("II. Construction");
                            string Construction = St.Substring(ConsFrom, ConsTo - ConsFrom);

                            //Get Construction machinery portion of record
                            int MachFrom = St.IndexOf("Construction Equipment and Machinery") + "Construction Equipment and Machinery".Length;
                            int MachTo = St.IndexOf("Construction Materials\r");
                            string Machinery = St.Substring(MachFrom, MachTo - MachFrom);

                            //Get Construction personnel portion of record
                            int PersFrom = St.IndexOf("Construction Personnel") + "Construction Personnel".Length;
                            int PersTo = St.IndexOf("Construction Equipment and Machinery");
                            string Personnel = St.Substring(PersFrom, PersTo - PersFrom);

                            //Get Quality inspection portion of record
                            int QCFrom = St.IndexOf("Quality Inspection") + "Quality Inspection".Length;
                            int QCTo = St.IndexOf("Constructional Safety");
                            string Quality = St.Substring(QCFrom, QCTo - QCFrom);

                            //Get Safety inspection portion of record
                            int SafeFrom = St.IndexOf("Constructional Safety") + "Constructional Safety".Length;
                            int SafeTo = St.IndexOf("and no phenomenon of improper operations.");
                            string Safety = St.Substring(SafeFrom, SafeTo - SafeFrom);

                            //Write the Supervision Log
                            LogWriter(wordDoc, oMissing, selection, rangeDoc, pageCnt, Date, Temperature, Construction, Machinery, Personnel, Quality, Safety);

                            //if (range.ShapeRange.Count > 0)
                            //{
                            //    foreach (Word.Shape shape in range.ShapeRange)
                            //    {
                            //        if (shape.TextFrame.HasText != 0)
                            //        {
                            //            LogWriter(wordDoc, oMissing, selection, rangeDoc, pageCnt, Date, Temperature, Construction, Machinery, Personnel, Quality, Safety);
                            //        }
                            //    }
                            //}
                            range = range.NextStoryRange;
                        }
                    }
                }

                static void LogWriter(Word.Document wordDoc, object oMissing, Word.Selection selection, Word.Range rangeDoc, int pageCnt, string Date, string Temperature, string Construction, string Machinery, string Personnel, string Quality, string Safety)
                {
                    //Copy the template page
                    wordDoc.Bookmarks[@"\Page"].Range.Copy();

                    //inserting a page break: first go to end of document
                    selection.EndKey(Word.WdUnits.wdStory, Word.WdMovementType.wdMove);

                    //insert a page break
                    object breakType = Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak;
                    selection.InsertBreak(ref breakType);

                    //Replace the text in the correct fields.
                    rangeDoc.Find.Execute(FindText: "{{Date}}", Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith: Date);
                    rangeDoc.Find.Execute(FindText: "{{TemperatureRecord}}", Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith: Temperature.Replace("\r",""));
                    rangeDoc.Find.Execute(FindText: "{{ConstructionWork}}", Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith: Construction.Replace("\r", ""));
                    rangeDoc.Find.Execute(FindText: "{{ConstructionMachinery}}", Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith: Machinery.Replace("\r", ""));
                    rangeDoc.Find.Execute(FindText: "{{ConstructionPersonnel}}", Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith: Personnel.Replace("\r", ""));
                    //rangeDoc.Find.Execute(FindText: "{{QualityInspection}}", Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith: Quality.Replace("\r", ""));
                    rangeDoc.Find.Execute(FindText: "{{SafetyInspection}}", Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith: Safety.Replace("\r", ""));

                    rangeDoc.Find.Execute("{{QualityInspection}}");
                    rangeDoc.Text = Quality.Replace("\r", "");

                    //Paste the template page onto a new one
                    selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting);                      
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone assist with a fix to read the other construction log pages and paste them correctly?

Comment: Hi, please edit your question and tell us what the incorrect behaviour is. It will make it easier for someone to help you.

Comment: The incorrect behaviour is... the code only copy pastes the first page. None of the others are either read in or searched through.

Answer (score 1):

you can insert below code to retrieve number of pages and call your function for all pages instead of one page

```
 Word.WdStatistic stat = Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages;
                int numpages = document.ComputeStatistics(stat, ref oMissing);

                int PageCnt = 1;
                while (PageCnt < numpages)
                {
                    SearchPerPage(wordDoc, oMissing, selection, rangeDoc, document, PageCnt);
                    PageCnt++;
                }
```

Comment: Ok. The copy pasting for the Supervision log is working. But the code is not seeing the other pages of the construction log.

Comment: Yes. I don't think the entire construction log is being read in maybe.

Comment: can you share us  your updated code and sample document?or you can try to print the PageCnt and check if it's covering all pages